# Computercraft: Can a coroutine do infinite loops?

Tags: lua, computercraft

I'm trying to do a software which can handle other programs, to start a program I use os.run(...) inside a coroutine,
Here is my code:

```
--VARS
local os_ver = "0.1"
local w,h = term.getSize() --Terminal size
local bar_b_color, bar_f_color --Background and foreground colors (bar)
local menu_b_color, menu_f_color --Background and foreground colors (menu)
local bg_image, bg_color --Background image, color
local root_dir = "/MaOS/"
local sys_dir = root_dir .. "sys/"
local usr_dir = root_dir .. "usr/"
local start_txt = "START" --The text printed in start button

local menus_index --Gui's index of menus

local prog_name --Name of the sel. program
local prog_path --Path of the sel. program

local win, process

--LOAD APIS
os.loadAPI(sys_dir .. "apis/flib")
os.loadAPI(sys_dir .. "apis/stdlib")
os.loadAPI(sys_dir .. "apis/gui")

--BASE FUNCS
function init() --Loads settings
    menu_b_color = tonumber(flib.getSetting(sys_dir .. "conf", "Background Menu Color"))
    menu_f_color = tonumber(flib.getSetting(sys_dir .. "conf", "Foreground Menu Color"))
    bar_b_color = tonumber(flib.getSetting(sys_dir .. "conf", "Background Bar Color"))
    bar_f_color = tonumber(flib.getSetting(sys_dir .. "conf", "Foreground Bar Color"))
    bg_image = paintutils.loadImage(flib.getSetting(sys_dir .. "conf", "Background Image Path"))
    bg_color = tonumber(flib.getSetting(sys_dir .. "conf", "Background Color"))
end

--PRE-MAIN
init()

--TABLES
--Menu: [1] -> Menu informations
local menus = {
    [1] = { --Start menu
        [1] = {is_shown = false; parent=0; x = 1; xx = 11; y = 1; yy = 6; b_color = menu_b_color; f_color = menu_f_color};
        [2] = {txt = "           "; cmd = function() end};
        [3] = {txt = " PROGRAMS >"; cmd = function()
                                             loadPrograms()
                                             gui.showMenu(menus_index, 3)
                                         end};
        [4] = {txt = " CUSTOMIZE "; cmd = function() launchShell("CUSTOMIZE", "/rom/programs/edit", sys_dir .. "conf") end};
        [5] = {txt = " SHELL     "; cmd = function() launchShell("SHELL", "/rom/programs/shell") end};
        [6] = {txt = " EXIT     >"; cmd = function() gui.showMenu(menus_index, 2) end};
        [7] = {txt = "           "; cmd = function() 
                                              win = window.create(term.current(),15,5,20,10, true)
                                              process = coroutine.create(function() os.run({term = win}, sys_dir .. "programs/Ice-Browser") end)
                                              coroutine.resume(process)
                                          end}
    };
    [2] = { --Exit menu
        [1] = {is_shown = false; parent=1; x = 12; xx = 23; y = 1; yy = 6; b_color = menu_b_color; f_color = menu_f_color};
        [2] = {txt = "          "; cmd = function() end};
        [3] = {txt = " SHUTDOWN "; cmd = function() os.shutdown() end};
        [4] = {txt = " REBOOT   "; cmd = function() os.reboot() end};
        [5] = {txt = "          "; cmd = function() end}
    };
    [3] = { --Programs menus
        [1] = {is_shown = false; parent=1; x = 12; xx = 25; y = 1; yy = 0; b_color = menu_b_color; f_color = menu_f_color};
        [2] = {txt = "              "; cmd = function() end};
    };
    [4] = { --Args menu
        [1] = {is_shown = false; parent=3; x = 26; xx = 38; y = 1; yy = 5; b_color = menu_b_color; f_color = menu_f_color};
        [2] = {txt = "               "; cmd = function() end};
        [3] = {txt = " RUN           "; cmd = function() launchShell(prog_name, prog_path, nil) end};
        [4] = {txt = " RUN WITH ARGS "; cmd = function() end};
        [5] = {txt = "               "; cmd = function() end};
    }
}

--FUNCS
function loadPrograms() --Load programs
    stdlib.clearTable(gui.menus[menus_index][3], 2)
    local programs = flib.getFiles(sys_dir .. "programs/")

    for _, program in pairs(programs) do
        name = " " .. program
        path = sys_dir .. "programs/" .. program

        if string.len(name) > (menus[3][1].xx-menus[3][1].x) then
            name = string.sub(name, 1, string.len(name)-4) .."... "
        elseif string.len(name)-1 < (menus[3][1].xx-menus[3][1].x) then
            for i=string.len(name),(menus[3][1].xx-menus[3][1].x),1 do
                name = name .. " "
            end
        end
        name = string.upper(name)

        table.insert(gui.menus[menus_index][3], {txt = name; cmd = function() end})
    end

    table.insert(gui.menus[menus_index][3], {txt = "              "; cmd = function() end})
    gui.menus[menus_index][3][1].yy = table.getn(programs)+1
end

function drawScr() --Draw screen
    --Draw bg
    term.setBackgroundColor(bg_color)
    term.clear()
    paintutils.drawImage(bg_image, 1, 2)

    --Draw bar
    term.setBackgroundColor(bar_b_color)
    term.setTextColor(bar_f_color) 
    term.setCursorPos(1, 1)
    term.clearLine()
    term.setCursorPos(w-#os_ver, 1)
    print(os_ver)
    term.setCursorPos(2, 1)
    print(start_txt)

    --Draw menus
    gui.drawAllShownMenus()

    if win ~= nil then win.redraw() end
end

function launchShell(title, path, arg)
    local shell_tab = multishell.launch({shell = shell}, path, arg)
    multishell.setTitle(shell_tab, title)
    multishell.setFocus(shell_tab)
    return shell_tab
end

--MAIN
multishell.setTitle(multishell.getCurrent(), "MaOS") --Set title of this shell
init()

menus_index = gui.loadMenuGroup(menus) --Load menus into gui

while true do
    drawScr()
    gui.handleMenuClick(2, 2+string.len(start_txt), 1, 1)
end
```

When I try to run "Ice-Browser", I immediately get the status, of the process, "suspended", that happens after drawning program.
The problem happens not when I don't use coroutines, that brings me to think, the problem is the coroutine.
My question is "Can a coroutine do infinite loops (while)"?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you use a lot of `[1]`, `[2]`, etc, when Lua will fill that all in for you, probably more efficiently than you can?

Comment: How can it do that, can you post me an example please?

Comment: It's also not clear what `os.run` does. As for how you do what I suggested, look up [Lua's table syntax](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.7).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, os.run runs a program in a specified environment (a Computercraft API), the sintax is os.run(table environment, string program_path [, string arg1 ...])

Comment: http://computercraft.info/wiki/Os.run

Comment: of course you can have inifinite loops in a coroutine's body. if you don't have a yield in your loop it doesn't make much sense to me though. (haven't read through your code)

Comment: I haven't finished my code, yet, but I will add some yields when a program loses focus :)

Comment: What are you really asking about? Of course coroutines can inf loop `coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function() while true do end end))`, but what exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved my problem, I didn't saw that the function os.pullEvent(...) yields the coroutine, thanks for the support